# flutter paypal via webview

Tags: paypal, webview, flutter

I am trying to integrate paypal payment for my flutter app via a webview.

```
return new MaterialApp(
routes: {
"/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
  url: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?    business=xxxx.com&cmd=_xclick&item_name=Hot+Sauce-12oz.+Bottle&amount=5.95&currency_code=USD",
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(
      "Payment",
    ),
  ),
)
},
);
```

when i run the page, the app closes unexpectedly with the error message

`Unsupported value: <FlutterError: 0x1c422d200> of type FlutterError
Lost connection to device.`

This is my flutter doctor.

```
Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.1 17B1003, locale en-HK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected devices (3 available)
```

Comment: did you get PayPal working with Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You forget the **initialRoute** Parameter in the **MaterialApp** 
the right way to do this is :

```
return new MaterialApp(
       initialRoute: '/',
       routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
              url: "https://www.paypal.com/",
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text(
                  "Payment",
                ),
              ),
            )
        },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) to integrate PayPal payment for your flutter app via a WebView.

An example with your sample url:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=xxxx.com&cmd=_xclick&item_name=Hot+Sauce-12oz.+Bottle&amount=5.95&currency_code=USD",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```